# How can I use such statement in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

```
{assign var=tmp_url value=setURI(array('page' => 1))}
```

It seems `array()` can't be used in smarty ?

I tried various ways ,but none work.

Anyone knows the trick?

Comment: This is irrelevant to your question but you might want to give up Smarty one day and use PHP templating. You wont be having problems like this.

Comment: can you give us more information about what your trying to do ? why are you trying to define an array in smarty to pass back to php funciton stored as a variable ? I really think your going about whatever your trying to do the wrong way

Comment: @mcgrailm, because the `setURI()` needs an array as the parameter. I'm not doing it wrong,trust me in this...

Comment: unless i"m looking at the wrong doc it only needs a string http://php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-seturl.php could you give me more detail about the scope of what your doing with them_url and where it its gonna come from what it will be used for

Comment: @mcgrailm,`setURI()` is my own function ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

In php file, write a function

```
<?php
 function getSetUri(){
   return setURI(array('page' => 1));
 }
?>
```

In template file, just call the function

```
{assign var=tmp_url value=getSetUri()}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell there is no native way of setting an array in smarty you could assign the array to smarty templete in your php and call it page

then accesss it in smarty like this

```
 {assign var=tmp_url value=setURI($page[1])}
```

or you could use a plug in. there are some other options in this [thread](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1252) but I'm not sure what will be best for you. you may need to find another way of doing what you want or modifying your function in some way so it can take a string

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`{php}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl) tags to assign the variable value in there:

```
<h1>Foo!{$var}</h1>
{php}
$this->assign('tmp_url', setURI($page[1]));
{/php}
<a href={$tmp_url}">bar</a>
```

Comment: I need to call it in the template.

Comment: If u try,`$this->assign` will fail.

Comment: then try something like `$smarty->assign()`. The `$this` example is from the smarty docs.